# Why i can't Display my Image in Table View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yoman.png"];
```

Am already add image to images.xcassets
why i still can't display.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: NO !! it runs smoothly

Comment: Make sure the image name is correct it could be case sensitive.  Also you can do NSLog(@"%@", cell.imageView.image); and see if its not nil to make sure you are setting the image correctly.

Comment: it shows like that <UIImage: 0x8c722a0>

Comment: What about the Table View Cell style is it custom or basic?

Comment: You can also add an image as `subview` to the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have all the following in your code:-

**No. 1:** Contains **UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate**

```
@interface TableViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation TableViewController
```

**No. 2:** Assign your viewController as the delegate and datasource of the tableView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.dataSource=self;
}
```

**No. 3:** Number of rows for your tableView

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 3;
}
```

**No. 4:** Example code for **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString * reuseIdentifier = nil ;
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yoman"];
return cell;
}
```

If you have all above and the image with the name "**yoman**" is inside your **Images.xcassets**, you should have no problem in displaying the image on the **tableviewcell**.